# Do every math operation derive from sum?

Tags: calculus

I've been told sometimes, that every math operation (sum, subtraction, exponentiation, square rooting, so on) can be transformed to a sum of operands. For example, subtraction can be made as $a + (-b)$. And multiplication $a * b = (a+a+a...)$ $b$ times`, $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}$

Is this true for every other operation? If possible could you please provide a proof?

Comment: It's not really a rigorous statement, so it doesn't really have a proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Unfortantly I lack in the enough math vocabulary to be rigorous about my statement (in english). If you got it I would be glad that you would suggest an edit.

Comment: I have no idea what your question means, so I'd probably not be able to help.

Comment: I think he means $a\cdot b = \underbrace{a + \cdots + a}_{\text{b times}}$, $a^b = \underbrace{a \cdot \cdots \cdot a}_{\text{b times}}$ and so on...

Comment: How to transcribe multiplication to a sum?

Comment: Not just multiplication, square rooting, log, etc

Comment: You just gave one example, viz., subtraction. It is true that it's defined by a sum. Can you give another example?

Comment: How do you write $-b$ in terms of addition?

Comment: @Kyson just gave the multiplication example, like sanjab

Comment: What if $b$ is not a natural number?

Comment: Permutation and functional inverses would be examples of what could be seen as operations that don't directly involve sums but then this depends on one's language.

Comment: @DanielV b=2 implies -b is -2, wich is a number present in integer set

Comment: @BrunoCosta If this sort of question interests you, then you might want to find a lecture on Peano Axioms.  It shows how all Non-Negative Integers can be described in terms of $0$ and "plus one".

Comment: @BrunoCosta Doesn't work for $b$ not a positive integer, however. What does it mean to add something to itself $-2$ times or $1/2$ times, or $\sqrt{2}$ times?

Comment: @Kyson in my original question I tried to explain that you need to have a set with the enough numbers, to express that very operation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews as long as that very something is 0, doesn't really matter. If not, none of your options is correct, well, it may be correct, as long you define the add operation to give the result you want. Is that you are trying to suggest?

Comment: I can't follow any of that, @BrunoCosta, but I'm pretty sure that is not what I'm saying. I'm saying the above definition of $a\cdot b$ using repeated addition doesn't work except for $b$ a positive integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Gotcha. Then I just need to add that a and b € N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a common misconception that $\times$ can be defined in terms of $+$. In fact, this only works in the integers; try computing $\sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{2}$ by "reducing it to $+$"!

Whoever told you this stuff is wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: Actualy, your example is messy, write sqrt(2) * sqrt(3) instead

Comment: @BrunoCosta, why is it messy? You cannot explain why the product is $2$ by trying to reduce the problem to repeated summation.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Ill be hitting my head on the wall for the weekend. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @BrunoCosta, rather than doing that, I suggest reading up about [commutative rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring), [integral domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain), [fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29), and the [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) construction. This is the correct framework in which to understand addition and multiplication.